# Selecting from a column with Ampersand(&)

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2005

The data type of the column is nvarchar. I can insert to the column properly using parameters. I see the ampersand character in the column when I view the table in sql server management studio.

My problem is when i'm selecting from the column in my application the ampersand character disappears.

Once I select the column I assign the value to a label like, `label1.Text = reader("column")`

The column in my table has a value of "Foo&Bar" but in my application it just shows as "FooBar".

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the ampersand was turning the next letter to a shortcut.

I just did a replace on the ampersand to 2 ampersands so it escapes.

`label1.Text = reader("column").ToString().Replace("&", "&&")`

Answer (score 0):

It is a property of the `Label` called `UseMnemonic`, set it to `False` to show the text `&` properly